# Agora.io: android.permission.CAMERA not compatible with Oculus device

Tags: oculus, agora.io

I'm developing an **VR Video Chat** application using **Agora.io** api and **Unity3D Engine**, in which a main user streams his webcam from a standalone Pc to users equippped with an Oculus device.

As soon as I try to upload the VR app to the Oculus Server, I got that error: 
*This app uses permission(s) that are not compatible with this device: android.permission.CAMERA*.

How do I overcome that issue?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't programmed for Oculus yet but here are some ideas:

First you may try just to set android:required=“false” in the manifest to see what happens?

Secondly check the official Oculus documentation here to see if helps? https://developer.oculus.com/blog/tech-note-android-plugins-and-permissions/?locale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

"You will need to modify your Android Manifest file. Because the Oculus Quest doesn’t have cameras (well, none that can be used for this demo) we will get rid of the camera use requirement ( ) located on line 9 in the folder Assets/Plugins/Android/AgoraRtcEngineKit.plugin "

This is a quote from this quick start tutorial which will get you up and running with Agora.io Video chat and Oculus Quest. It explains how to stream your webcam from a standalone PC to Oculus Quest. https://medium.com/@jake_agora.io/live-realtime-video-to-vr-oculus-quest-6bbb74e4fc63

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else falls into this. The solution posted where you remove the entry from the Agora included manifest doesn't work anymore, and I can't identify where its being added from, perhaps Agora can post a solution. The only way around it is to export from Unity, edit the Manifest to remove the unwanted camera permissions and then build in Android Studio.